# $http service not triggering success or error callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get

This is my partial view -

```
<form action="" ng-controller="Ctrl as forgot" name="forgotForm" ng-submit="forgotForm.$valid && forgot.sendPost()">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="email" ng-model="forgot.emailData" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info submitButton">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is a method in my controller -

```
self.sendPost = function() {
        console.log(self.emailData); //the value I entered in the input box
        $http.get("https://api?email=rq895@msstae.edu")
            .success(function(data, response, headers, config) {
                 console.log("Success Data " + response);
             })

             .error(function(data, response, headers, config) {
                 console.debug("Returned Data ");
             });
    };
```

For example, if I enter the value `abc@abc.com` in the input box, I see that the actual value I enter in the form has been sent to the api (The value of self.emailData). I get a response of 200.

Following are the problems I am having,

1) Why is `self.emailData` being sent when I am clearly specifying the email address to be sent to be `rq895@msstae.edu`

2) Since I get a response of 200, why is the success callback not being fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success and error are deprecated. Try refactoring your code to something like:

```
self.sendPost = function() {
    console.log(self.emailData); //the value I entered in the input box
    $http.get("https://api?email=rq895@msstae.edu")
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
       console.log(response)
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.debug(response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First Tip : 
 Please dont have the business logic in the controllers. Move it in services and inject the service in the controller.
As per your answer try using **then** with success and error handlers. AN example of it is given beloe

```
$http.get(URL).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(){

}

function errorCallback(){

}
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy Learning :)